# I can not create a Webhooks in gitlab to integrate jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Prepare the environment in jenkins to integrate sonarqube and gitlab, with sonarqube I have no problem but when I try to create Webhooks, it does not let me enter a URL localhost.

If someone can help me to give access to my URL.

[image: Gitlab Webhooks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported in [gitlab-ce issue 49315](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/49315), and linked to the documentation "[Webhooks and insecure internal web services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/security/webhooks.html)"

> Because Webhook requests are made by the GitLab server itself, these have complete access to everything running on the server (`http://localhost:123`) or within the server’s local network (`http://192.168.1.12:345`), even if these services are otherwise protected and inaccessible from the outside world.
>
> If a web service does not require authentication, Webhooks can be used to trigger destructive commands by getting the GitLab server to make POST requests to endpoints like `http://localhost:123/some-resource/delete`.
>
> To prevent this type of exploitation from happening, starting with GitLab 10.6, all Webhook requests to the current GitLab instance server address and/or in a private network will be forbidden by default.
> That means that all requests made to 127.0.0.1, ::1 and 0.0.0.0, as well as IPv4 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 and IPv6 site-local (ffc0::/10) addresses won’t be allowed.

If you really needs this:

> This behavior can be overridden by enabling the option “Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services” in the “Outbound requests” section inside the Admin area under Settings (`/admin/application_settings/network`):

Comment: That is, if I enter the ip of my localhost, I would not have to have a problem, right? but even if I have access problems with jenkins